# How to extract the levels in a column variable into separate new columns;

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Data Frame;

```
Day Diet weight 
1    A   52
1    A   50
1    B   25
1    B   30
2    A   26
2    A   10
2    B   15
2    B   34
```

Expected output;

```
Day1  Day2  Diet
 52    26    A
 50    10    A
 25    15    B
 30    34    B
```

Two levels of the DAY variable should be added into new columns. plot a grapgh x= day1 and y= day 2

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequential counter to uniquely identify rows per Day and Diet, then pivot the dataframe to reshape finally add the Day prefix in column names and reset the level 1 index

```
df['ix'] = df.groupby(['Day', 'Diet']).cumcount()
result = (
    df
    .pivot(index=['ix', 'Diet'], columns='Day', values='weight')
    .add_prefix('Day')
    .reset_index(level=1)
)
```

---

```
Day Diet  Day1  Day2
ix                  
0      A    52    26
0      B    25    15
1      A    50    10
1      B    30    34
```